# Excel macOS: Checkbox to hide/unhide rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, macos, checkbox, row

I'm trying to find a solution to do the following in Excel on macOS: A checkbox should hide/unhide rows based on the cell value in a certain row. In concrete: When clicking the checkbox "closed" I want to hide all rows with the value "closed" in row D. When deselecting the checkbox the rows with the value "closed" in row D should be unhidden.

My coding abilities are quite limited and I searched the web for an answer in vain. I'd appreciate help with this!